# Dynamic PDF download, Blank Issue

Tags: java, pdf, dynamic, process, download

1. There is a URL. For Example:
   http://www.example.com/test.pdf
2. When someone hits above URL, an asynchronous call is made internally to pull the content of the PDF and lay on the page.
3. Only when you scroll to the next page, another asynchronous call is made for that page. Else it is blank by default.
4. If you try to download the entire PDF, without viewing all pages, It is blank.

I wrote a Java program to download the PDF, without viewing the page. Which brings me blank PDF.

How do i download the PDF? Any ideas? How to mimic the manual process?

Comment: Um. What is wrong with your code? Well, it appears to be missing.

Answer (score -1):

When you download files (PDF) there are two ways to save

Initial
1. Click on the download link
2. Click the right mouse button
3. Choose Save Goal (save goal)
4. Place the place and click Save

the second
1. Click the download link
2. When you open the file there is a bar from the File menu
3. We choose (save a copy)
4. Place the place and click Save

There are many programs that support opening files in PDF format.
   Example: Adobe Reader